# How to exclude js file from src directory in webpack config file?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I'm writing react application with given structure (simplified):

```
src/
├── containers/
│   ├── ...
│   ├── ...
│   ├── ...
│   └── ...
├── SourceResolver/
│   └── SourceResolver.js
│ 
└── App.js
```

SourceResolver.js is a class which contains one method. This method is used in files which are localized into containers folder. I simply create object of this class and then call defined method:

new SourceResolver().getSource();

I don't want to minify this file (or even directory). I want to leave this file like it is in production build (as separte file). Leter if someone would like to change this method it will be possible even in production build.

How can achieve this? I tried to exlude this file/directory in webpack file, but with no success. Is it even possible?

Here is my webpack file https://pastebin.com/xS6QkKzb

Here is my changed webpack file, I tried to add exclude everyhere because I don't know why it doesn't work. https://pastebin.com/6brcNRq3

Comment: Did you try excluding from babel-loader? How did you try to exclude? Can you update your post?

Comment: Yes, I did. But still it doesn't work for me, maybe I'm doing something wrong. I added my edited webpack file as you asked.